# OpenSSL Subca and SAN Website Certificate

Tags: https, openssl, ssl-certificate, pki

currently in my work, we have a PKI made with Microsoft Certificate Authority Role.

- Root CA: Out of domain and turned off.
- Sub CA: Domain connected, provides CRL (using IIS) and sign certificates for domain computers.

My idea is to reproduce the environment with Linux and Openssl. At least my first objective is for the internal webs.

I followed this tutorial https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/ and everything works fine.

- I create the Root CA and self-sign it.
- I create the Subca, I sign it with the Root and verify that the certification chain is correct -> OK

The problem is when I try to create a website certificate with SAN (Subject Alternative Name) field. This is the way I create the csr and key files.

```
openssl req -nodes -new -newkey rsa:4096 \
    -keyout test3.psc.local.key \
    -out test3.psc.local.csr \
    -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:test3.psc.local" \
    -subj "/C=ES/ST=Barcelona/L=Barcelona/O=GRG-CA/OU=GRG-CA/emailAddress=your@email.dot/CN=test3.psc.local/"
```

If I check the CSR with OpenSSL command `openssl x509 -noout -text -in test3.psc.local.csr` the SAN field exist and has the value that I set in generation command (test3.psc.local).

```
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Subject: C = ES, ST = Barcelona, L = Barcelona, O = GRG-CA, OU = GRG-CA, emailAddress = your@email.dot, CN = test3.psc.local
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:dc:17:8c:c1:90:26:16:67:4e:16:b3:0c:9b:2b:
                    3d:ec:8e:94:47:b9:8c:b8:14:ac:be:09:b8:bb:f5:
                    d8:f2:79:26:a6:9d:2f:73:5b:48:64:cb:3a:c2:f6:
                    bd:6d:7f:fd:7e:f2:... bla bla bla
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
        Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:test3.psc.local
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         b5:f0:7f:ba:ab:dc:f6:ee:37:c5:fa:14:27:6b:09:a8:b8:08:
         0b:4f:ed:2a:44:72:cd:8d:50:47:79:7d:69:e3:73:cc:14:89:
         b6:69:ff:61:bb:79:0a:41:12:32:c7:d1:6f:1d:a4:e4:cb:ef:
         16:56:35:fd:44:0a:0c:70:fc:45:1f:7d:c2:d7:4c:ca:bd:66:
         6d:e6:41:74:56:2c:... bla bla bla
```

When I try to sign the certificate with OpenSSL Subca I execute with this command.

```
openssl ca -config intermediate/sub-ca-openssl.cnf \
    -extensions server_cert    \
    -days 375 -notext -md sha512     \
    -in /root/ca/test3.psc.local.csr     \
    -out /root/ca/test3.psc.local.crt
```

But the SAN field isn't present, so Firefox, Chrome and others dont trust in certificate. Only IE11 trust.

```
Using configuration from intermediate/sub-ca-openssl.cnf
Enter pass phrase for /root/ca/intermediate/private/intermediate.key.pem:
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature ok
Certificate Details:
        Serial Number: 4099 (0x1003)
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 12 20:58:53 2022 GMT
            Not After : Oct 22 20:58:53 2023 GMT
        Subject:
            countryName               = ES
            stateOrProvinceName       = Barcelona
            localityName              = Barcelona
            organizationName          = GRG-CA
            organizationalUnitName    = GRG-CA
            commonName                = test3.psc.local
            emailAddress              = your@email.dot
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            Netscape Cert Type:
                SSL Server
            Netscape Comment:
                OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                BC:11:0C:2E:08:FA:7D:91:16:1E:AC:0E:12:DA:80:69:64:F7:F1:58
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:7D:B8:7B:9E:59:4F:70:7B:F8:2C:1F:2B:0C:A2:E9:90:3C:D1:7A:71
                DirName:/C=ES/ST=Barcelona/L=Barcelona/O=GRG-CA/OU=GRG-CA/CN=GRG Root CA
                serial:10:00

        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
            TLS Web Server Authentication
        X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:

            Full Name:
              URI:http://pki.dominio.com/intermediate.crl

Certificate is to be certified until Oct 22 20:58:53 2023 GMT (375 days)
Sign the certificate? [y/n]:
```

Content of SUB CA config:

```
[ ca ]
default_ca = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
dir               = /root/ca/intermediate
certs             = $dir/certs
crl_dir           = $dir/crl
new_certs_dir     = $dir/newcerts
database          = $dir/subordinate-ca-database.txt
serial            = $dir/serial
RANDFILE          = $dir/private/.rand

private_key       = $dir/private/intermediate.key.pem
certificate       = $dir/certs/intermediate.cert.pem

crlnumber         = $dir/crlnumber
crl               = $dir/crl/intermediate.crl.pem
crl_extensions    = crl_ext
default_crl_days  = 365

default_md        = sha512

name_opt          = ca_default
cert_opt          = ca_default

default_days      = 5840
preserve          = no
policy            = subca_policy

[ subca_policy ]
countryName             = optional
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[ req ]
default_bits        = 4096
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
string_mask         = utf8only
default_md          = sha512
x509_extensions     = v3_ca

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                     = Country Name (2 letter code)
stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name
localityName                    = Locality Name
0.organizationName              = Organization Name
organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name
commonName                      = Common Name
emailAddress                    = Email Address

# Optionally, specify some defaults.
countryName_default             = ES
stateOrProvinceName_default     = Barcelona
localityName_default            = Barcelona
0.organizationName_default      = GRG-CA
organizationalUnitName_default  = GRG-CA
#emailAddress_default           =


[ v3_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical CA (`man x509v3_config`).
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign

[ v3_intermediate_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical intermediate CA (`man x509v3_config`).
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true, pathlen:0
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign

[ usr_cert ]
# Extensions for client certificates (`man x509v3_config`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
nsCertType = client, email
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Client Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
keyUsage = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth, emailProtection

[ server_cert ]
# Extensions for server certificates (`man x509v3_config`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
nsCertType = server
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer:always
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
crlDistributionPoints = URI:http://pki.dominio.com/intermediate.crl

[ ocsp ]
# Extension for OCSP signing certificates (`man ocsp`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = critical, OCSPSigning

[ crl_ext ]
# Extension for CRLs (`man x509v3_config`).
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always

[ crl_info ]
URI.0 = http://pki.dominio.com/sub-ca.crl
URI.1 = https://www.dominio.com/pki/sub-ca.crl
```

I've read that I need a SAN.conf with alternate names in SUBCA server for sign... and change all Alternate Names for every CSR (website) that I want to sign... but in Microsoft Subca I dont need to tell that fields when I sign the CSR (only on generation, same command as I write before).

There is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ca.html) for OpenSSL's CA command:

**copy_extensions**

> determines how extensions in certificate requests should be handled.
> If set to none or this option is not present then extensions are
> ignored and not copied to the certificate. If set to copy then any
> extensions present in the request that are not already present are
> copied to the certificate. If set to copyall then all extensions in
> the request are copied to the certificate: if the extension is already
> present in the certificate it is deleted first. See the WARNINGS
> section before using this option.
>
> The main use of this option is to allow a certificate request to
> supply values for certain extensions such as subjectAltName.

Also, you should understand that using OpenSSL as a CA isn't the best idea.  There is no logging, no multi-person control etc. - basically no security. Read the WARNINGS section of the same man page.

Comment: The problem (as I read) , copy is a bad idea, because someone can make a CSR with CA:True and it will be copied. But reading again... its seems if I set CA:False it will be False.

Just for learn, which CA is recomended instead OpenSSL ?

Comment: @Guille - Another reason not to use OpenSSL in production ;-)  Which CA is an opinion, so probably off topic.  You have already a Microsoft CA - keep using it!  EJBCA has a free version...

Comment: thanks for your help , at least for the moment (years) I dont have intention to change it, but I want try some other tools for learning purposes. I will check EJBCA too, thanks a lot